# How to access hyperlink of attribute in HtmlDocument

Tags: html, hyperlink, webbrowser-control, getattribute

So I decided to create a program that deals with HTMLDocument of a website, and I understand now how to do getAttributeByID. However, how, after you get the attribute, do you get the HYPERLINK of the attribute, and store it as a String?? I've tried to search up and down the Microsoft Document of getAttributeByID() for the solutions, but can't find ANY.

What do I do?

This is the website btw: view-source:https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E9%AB%98%E9%BA%97%E5%8F%B2/%E5%8D%B7%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E5%85%AD#%E5%BB%A3%E5%B7%9E%E7%89%A7

View the page source by pressing Ctrl+U

Also, to find the attribute's id, do Ctrl+F and search for (without the quotations ofc) "ca-edit"

Answer (score 0):

You would want to get the element, then use a querySelector to get the anchor tag inside. Lastly, you would want to get the href attribute of that anchor tag.

And example of this would look like this:

```
const element = document.getElementById('ca-edit');
const a = element.querySelector('a');
const href = a.getAttribute('href');
```

You can technically also do it all in one line:

```
const element = document.getElementById('ca-edit').querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
```

Then you can do whatever you'd like with that href.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I dont believe there is such function in Js for getAttributeByID.
I would advise on for using querySelectorAll that uses Css selector as input and serves your case very well.
querySelectorAll returns an array of all the element it can find you can then iterate over what you find.
[querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Once we have that sorted next bit is href attribute two ways to get that either use getAttribute function or better yet href is also a property so you can call it directly as following  anchorelement.href
[hred property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_href.asp)

now that we have this sorted  below is an example for your consumption

```js
hyperlinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
console.log(hyperlinks[0].href);

for (i = 0; i < hyperlinks.length; i++) {
  console.log(hyperlinks[i].href);
}
```

```html
<nav id="sidenav" class="refnav__obj"><div class="scrollcontainer"><div class="title">Properties</div><ul><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/haspersonaldata" class="item">haspersonaldata</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/id" class="item">id</a></li><li class=" " ><a id='justme' href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isabstract" class="item">isabstract</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isattachment" class="item">isattachment</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isdomain" class="item">isdomain</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/islink" class="item">islink</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isobject" class="item">isobject</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/keephistorydays" class="item">keephistorydays</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linkfrom" class="item">linkfrom</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linkfromtype" class="item">linkfromtype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linkto" class="item">linkto</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linktotype" class="item">linktotype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/metatype" class="item">metatype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/parent" class="item">parent</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/parenttype" class="item">parenttype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/tag" class="item">tag</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/title" class="item">title</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/wrdschema" class="item">wrdschema</a></li></ul><div class="title">Functions</div><ul><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/closeentity" class="item">CloseEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/closeordeleteentity" class="item">CloseOrDeleteEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/createattribute" class="item">CreateAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/createchangeset" class="item">CreateChangeSet</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/createentity" class="item">CreateEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteallentities" class="item">DeleteAllEntities</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteattribute" class="item">DeleteAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteentities" class="item">DeleteEntities</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteentity" class="item">DeleteEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteself" class="item">DeleteSelf</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/enrich" class="item">Enrich</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/ensureentity" class="item">EnsureEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/findids" class="item">FindIds</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/generateuniqueattributetag" class="item">GenerateUniqueAttributeTag</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getattribute" class="item">GetAttribute</a></li><li class="active " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getattributebyid" class="item">GetAttributeById</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getchanges" class="item">GetChanges</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdefaultvalues" class="item">GetDefaultValues</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdescendantids" class="item">GetDescendantIds</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomval" class="item">GetDomVal</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvals" class="item">GetDomVals</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltag" class="item">GetDomValTag</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltags" class="item">GetDomValTags</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltitle" class="item">GetDomValTitle</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltitles" class="item">GetDomValTitles</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getentity" class="item">GetEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getentityfield" class="item">GetEntityField</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getentityfields" class="item">GetEntityFields</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/geteventmasks" class="item">GetEventMasks</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getnewentityguid" class="item">GetNewEntityGUID</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getnewentityid" class="item">GetNewEntityId</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/hasattribute" class="item">HasAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/importentities" class="item">ImportEntities</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/listattributes" class="item">ListAttributes</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/listchangesets" class="item">ListChangesets</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/listdomvals" class="item">ListDomVals</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/runquery" class="item">RunQuery</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/search" class="item">Search</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/updateattribute" class="item">UpdateAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/updateentity" class="item">UpdateEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/updatemetadata" class="item">UpdateMetadata</a></li></ul></div></nav>
```

```js
hyperlinks = document.querySelectorAll('#justme');
//or could nested since nav bar has id sidenav
hyperlinks = document.querySelectorAll('#sidenav #justme');
for (i = 0; i < hyperlinks.length; i++) {
  console.log(hyperlinks[i].href);
}
```

```html
<nav id="sidenav" class="refnav__obj"><div class="scrollcontainer"><div class="title">Properties</div><ul><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/haspersonaldata" class="item">haspersonaldata</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/id" class="item">id</a></li><li class=" " ><a id='justme' href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isabstract" class="item">isabstract</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isattachment" class="item">isattachment</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isdomain" class="item">isdomain</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/islink" class="item">islink</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/isobject" class="item">isobject</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/keephistorydays" class="item">keephistorydays</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linkfrom" class="item">linkfrom</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linkfromtype" class="item">linkfromtype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linkto" class="item">linkto</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/linktotype" class="item">linktotype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/metatype" class="item">metatype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/parent" class="item">parent</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/parenttype" class="item">parenttype</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/tag" class="item">tag</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/title" class="item">title</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/wrdschema" class="item">wrdschema</a></li></ul><div class="title">Functions</div><ul><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/closeentity" class="item">CloseEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/closeordeleteentity" class="item">CloseOrDeleteEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/createattribute" class="item">CreateAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/createchangeset" class="item">CreateChangeSet</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/createentity" class="item">CreateEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteallentities" class="item">DeleteAllEntities</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteattribute" class="item">DeleteAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteentities" class="item">DeleteEntities</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteentity" class="item">DeleteEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/deleteself" class="item">DeleteSelf</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/enrich" class="item">Enrich</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/ensureentity" class="item">EnsureEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/findids" class="item">FindIds</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/generateuniqueattributetag" class="item">GenerateUniqueAttributeTag</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getattribute" class="item">GetAttribute</a></li><li class="active " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getattributebyid" class="item">GetAttributeById</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getchanges" class="item">GetChanges</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdefaultvalues" class="item">GetDefaultValues</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdescendantids" class="item">GetDescendantIds</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomval" class="item">GetDomVal</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvals" class="item">GetDomVals</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltag" class="item">GetDomValTag</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltags" class="item">GetDomValTags</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltitle" class="item">GetDomValTitle</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getdomvaltitles" class="item">GetDomValTitles</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getentity" class="item">GetEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getentityfield" class="item">GetEntityField</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getentityfields" class="item">GetEntityFields</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/geteventmasks" class="item">GetEventMasks</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getnewentityguid" class="item">GetNewEntityGUID</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/getnewentityid" class="item">GetNewEntityId</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/hasattribute" class="item">HasAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/importentities" class="item">ImportEntities</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/listattributes" class="item">ListAttributes</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/listchangesets" class="item">ListChangesets</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/listdomvals" class="item">ListDomVals</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/runquery" class="item">RunQuery</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/search" class="item">Search</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/updateattribute" class="item">UpdateAttribute</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/updateentity" class="item">UpdateEntity</a></li><li class=" " ><a href="https://www.webhare.dev/reference/wrd/symbol/wrdtype2017/updatemetadata" class="item">UpdateMetadata</a></li></ul></div></nav>
```

document.querySelectorAll('a') is finding all the anchors

document.querySelectorAll('#justme') is finding specific element by id justme
document.querySelectorAll('#sidenav #justme') is first finding specific element by id called sidenav then searches for id justme inside it very handy since you could have multiple elements but identify them by ids and this can sift through them.

Comment: Oh I forgot, I'm talking about Visual Basic. Sorry.